# Object Required error when using End property

Tags: vba, excel

I have read similiar "object required" error questions, but I can't see how those apply to my problem, so I am asking another question.

Here is my code;

```
Private Sub cmd_next_prime_Click()

p_strt = Range("A2")
p_end = p_strt.End(xlDown)
p_current = Range(p_strt, p_end)

For i = 1 To p_current.Cells.Count
    MsgBox p_current.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i


End Sub
```

I am trying to set `p_current` to range starting from A2 to end of filled cells. Later, I will loop through them and use the values somehow. But I am getting error on this line;

```
p_end = p_strt.End(xlDown)
```

I am very new to excel vba, and I have no idea what might be causing this error.

Comment: Very simple.......use **Set** for the ranges.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Set** :

```
Set p_strt = Range("A2")
```

etc.

**EDIT**

We use **Set** whenever we setup an Object

Here is an example:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A2")
    Dim rr As Range
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rr = Range(r, Cells(N, "A"))
    rr.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? What does set do? Why do I need it here?

Comment: Whenever you deal with objects (rather than data) you need to `Set` the object.  This was something I banged my head against repeatedly when I started coding VBA.  So in this case all three of your variables are defining range objects, which all need to be `Set` rather than just declared.

Comment: Any time @Gary'sStudent.